# open and closing modal

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a modal that I want to open/close on the click of the button, however, there seems to be an issue where sometimes it works and most of the time it won't.

From the code I've added below, it runs fine here. However, when I add it to my website it doesn't seem to work for me.

[Maximizemedia.co.uk](http://maximizemedia.co.uk)

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
 document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
 document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.bg-modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.93);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: none;
}

.modal-content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.modal-content input,
textarea,
.modal-content a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 15px auto;
}


.close {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="button" class="button">click me</a>

 <div class="bg-modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close">+</div>
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name">
                <input type="text" placeholder="email">
                <input type="text" placeholder="phone number">
                <textarea name="comment" id="" cols="30" rows="10">What would you like to chat to me about?</textarea>
                <a class="button">Send message</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is executed before the page is loaded, so `document.getElementById('button')` is null. Try moving your `<script>` tag at the end of the `<body>` element.

Comment: Great stuff! That seems to have done the trick, thanks for your help.

Comment: I just have another quick query. Do you have any idea how to make the page un-scrollable when the modal is open?

Answer (score 0):

Are these three segments of code all in one HTML file or in 3 separate files?

If the answer is (a) that they're all in the same HTML file, then see Iso's answer - the JavaScript has to run after the browser has parsed the HTML.

However, the fact that this *sometimes* works (particularly on your local computer) suggests that you actually have 3 separate files: a script file, an HTML file and a CSS file. On localhost, there is virtually no delay between your browser sending the requests for each file and them arriving. This means that the DOM (Document Object Model - as specified by the HTML) has already been parsed by the browser by the time the JavaScript runs - and so all works as you expect.

However, when you load this over a network (putting it on your website) each file takes longer to arrive to the browser and it's possible that the Document Object Model has not finished loading by the time the JavaScript runs - which will lead to `document.getElementById('button')` being null as Iso says.

If you're using jQuery, put your code inside [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), which will wait for the DOM to be ready before running it. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
    });

    document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

If you're not using jQuery, put your code inside `$( window ).on('load')`, like so:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
    });

    document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

However, bear in mind that if jQuery is available then the second approach is sub-optimal because it will wait until *everything* has loaded (including all images etc) before running the code, so if your user is on a slow internet connection it may take several seconds for the click handler to register. The jQuery approach will run the code after the DOM is ready but won't wait for all images etc to load as well - so the click handler gets registered much faster.